# Php Csv export with keep column value leading zero

Tags: php

I want keep leading zero value in csv column with  php for example
Zip Code - always 5 digits - if we pull the file, we should be able to automatically pull the zips and the ones that start with 0 
eg 07106 instead of 7106.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: check if it is a 5 digit number, else append a zero at start.

Comment: you should check this before asking whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Excel (and possibly Numbers) will automatically remove the leading zeros, it might be worth checking that this isn't happening and the Cell formatting is correct (String|Text).

Comment: are you sure they are in the csv file

Comment: I have tried this LPAD(zip, 5, 0)